# python import module from parent package

Tags: python, import, module, package, parent

I have the following directory structure

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    bar/
        __init__.py
        myfile.py
```

In myfile.py I have:
    import settings

I get the following error: `ImportError: No module named settings`, why? How can I efectively import the `settings` file from `myfile.py`

Answer (score 24):

From http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references :

```
from .. import settings
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried that but I get ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Comment: @danielrvt: Are you running `myfile.py` as a script? Scripts within packages are not really supported in Python (despite it being frequently requested). Make a helper script at the top level that imports `foo.bar.myfile` and you'll be all set.

Comment: Yes, I'm running it as a script, didn't get the part about making a helper script

Comment: @danielrvt: put it in a script in foo's parent directory: `from foo.bar.myfile import main; main()` (setuptools generates similar scripts automatically based on entry points specified in your setup.py)

Comment: The solution given @Adrián dosen't work with python 3.3 + since i get a relative import a top-level package. @ Blckknght +1

Comment: @Blckknght Please post your comment as an answer it will help many peoples.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another method that seems more clear:

In `foo.__init__.py`:

```
  __all__ = ['settings', ..(all other modules at 'foo' level you want to show)...]
```

In `myfile.py`:

```
# instead of "from .. import..." 
  from foo import settings 
  print settings.theThing
```

Comment: In my case, it writes "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo' ". How to make visible foo from its own subdirectory?