# Python - How do I import parent package from extended namespace

Tags: python, namespaces, package, extend

So I have two different packages. The first one is my main package "bobzilla", and the other package extends the first "bobzilla.structure".

I.e.

```
bobzilla/
  __init__.py
```

Where bobzilla/__init__.py contains:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar=bar
```

And:

```
bobzilla/
  __init__.py
  structure/
    __init__.py
```

Where bobzilla/structure/__init__.py contains:

```
import bobzilla
foo=Foo("bar")
```

When executing the bobzilla/structure/__init__.py I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Foo'
```

My question is, how can I reference the namespace "bobzilla" from "bobzilla.structure" without "bobzilla.structure" overwriting it.

**Note:**

The one who set the *"This question may already have an answer here"*  is wrong. I have already tried that and it did not work. This is two different packages, not the same one.

Comment: You cannot. Namespace packages **must** be empty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python import module from parent package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250058/python-import-module-from-parent-package)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay, so I just remove bobzilla/__init__.py from the bobzilla.structure-package then make it a namespace package, and it should work?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? And are you attempting to create a classic explicit namespace package, or a PEP420-style implicit one? If the former, can you show us your relevant `extend_path` or `declare_namespace` code? If the later… you are using Python 3.3 or later, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to create a namespace package without creating a namespace package, which… isn't going to work.

To explicitly designate a package as a namespace package, you need to use the [`pkgutil`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.extend_path) library (or the fancier stuff in `setuptools`), something like this at the top of `bobzilla/__init__.py`:

```
__path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

If you want an [*implicit* namespace package](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/), you can do that in Python 3.3 and later… but only if `bobzilla` is *empty*. Implicit namespace packages cannot contain an `__init__.py` file, and will never have any contents but their modules. (Well, you could create an implicit namespace package, then add a subpackage or external module that explicit adds things into it once it's created… but I'm not sure why you'd do that.)

Answer (score 0):

`bobzilla/structure/__init__.py` should be:

```
from bobzilla import Foo
foo=Foo("bar")
```

Testing the above with identical structure and code mention in the question. `bobzilla` being in `/path/to/test`. Result:

```
>>> from site import addsitedir
>>> addsitedir("/path/to/test")
>>> import bobzilla.structure as struc
>>> struc.foo
<bobzilla.Foo object at 0x7f2f8c716810>
>>>
```

Comment: 'from .. import bobzilla' did not work. Only got 'ImportError: cannot import name bobzilla'.

Comment: The thing is that the Foo class is inside of bobzilla/__init__.py, it's not bobzilla/foo.py (if that makes sense). So what you suggested only error'd with 'ImportError: cannot import name Foo'.

Comment: @endlessretry Result of testing the above added to the answer. The error is not reproducible given the description in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import bozilla.structure as struct
import bozilla
```

A working example with the `NLTK` library, http://nltk.org:

```
>>> import nltk.corpus as corpus
>>> nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'nltk' is not defined
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.corpus
<LazyModule 'nltk.corpus'>
>>> corpus
<LazyModule 'nltk.corpus'>
```