# Importing module from parent directory starting with a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuration, python-import, python-module

I currently have a Python file that needs to import another Python file in the parent directory. The problem is that the file that I want to import, has a name that starts with a number.

The structure of the files is as following:

```
parent/
├── 123.py
└── child/
    └─── my_file.py
```

I want to import the **123.py** file, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

No. That is not a valid Python module name. Call it something else, beginning with a letter.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is a good piece of advice in that if you are naming a module/variable, you shouldn't start it with a number. But if you have to import a module named like that, it is still possible.

For example, to access variable `x` from module `123.py`:

```
>>> from importlib import import_module
>>> onetwothree = import_module('123')
>>> onetwothree.x
```

Regarding the other part of your question, the module being in the parent directory, you can first append that directory to your sys path:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('path/to/dir')
```

Answer (score 0):

[Read more about naming conventions from PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names)

Mentioned above, it's not a preferable to name modules as numbers because it makes things more complicated than they should be. PEP 8 also recommends that naming is lowercase, using underscores to increase readability. PEP 8 aren't a set of rules, but guidelines. If it's absolutely necessary that you need the module name as a number, you can follow Lgiro's answer.

Another way you can import is using `__init__.py` files and relative imports.

```
parent/
├──__init__.py
├── parent.py
└── child/
    ├───__init__.py
    └─── child.py
```

Then in child.py

```
from .. import parent
```

[Question related to relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250058/python-import-module-from-parent-package)