# Import a library from parent directory | python

Tags: python

I want to import a library in parent directory, the structure of the folder looks like:

[image: Image of files and folder structure]

So, how i can **import** this lib?

Comment: can you try ? ```from lib import library ```

Comment: Make lib a package(add `__init__.py` file) and then `from lib import library`

Comment: not works ImportError: No module named lib

Comment: If you're firing up `main.py` directly, you won't be able to import beyod parent package.

Comment: https://imgur.com/ybDnUpT

Comment: @nicolas Hey man, you have 2 folders. you can't call the library from the "main" folder. If you want to import "library.py", then save it in the same folder. I mean, cut & paste "library.py" into "main" folder. then you try    " from main  import library"

Comment: This could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250058/python-import-module-from-parent-package

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several solutions to this problem.

A simple and straight forward one would be to add the path to your library. This solution is useful in case you are prototyping, and you don't want to make an actual package yet.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/package_or_module")
```

Then you can go on with `import my_package`.

Here is one example.

```
➜  cat Desktop/folder_X/my_package.py
hello = 'Hi there!'
➜  cat Desktop/folder_Y/run.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/xxx/Desktop/folder_X')

from my_package import *

print(hello)
➜  python Desktop/folder_Y/run.py
Hi there!
```

A better way, in general, is to make a proper package. It requires a bit more knowledge, but it worths the effort. Please, read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) on that.

Comment: You cannot import beyond parent package anyway. Brush your teeth at least twice a day and keep your imports clean.

Comment: @PiotrRarus-ReinstateMonica Try it out and then remove the downvote. It just works.

Comment: @PiotrRarus-ReinstateMonica Apologies accepted. But in general, I do think that hacking your way out of a problem is an excellent way of learning. I would not use such a trick in production, but to play with code, definetly!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you [read](https://towardsdatascience.com/whats-init-for-me-d70a312da583) about how `python` handles imports. It's not a proper way to structure your package. You may grunge over it a bit, but it's the only way to stay concious about your structure and dependencies. Otherwise you'll have a mess like in `C#`, where `vs-studio` just imports everything from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the parrent Directory to sys.path, but this is not the way how this should be do.

Answer (score 0):

Make lib a package(add `__init__.py` file in the folder) and then `from lib import library`.