# Import a module form a parent file to a module in a child file

Tags: python, python-import

Suppose I have this tree

> ```
> \Package
>     __init__.py #Empty 
>     A.py 
>     ...
>     \subpackage
>          __init__.py #Empty
>          B.py
>          ...
>          \subsubpackage
>               __init__.py #Empty
>               C.py #My main file
> ```

So I would like to import modules `A.py, B.py` into `C.py`.
I know, I could use `sys.path.append(...)` to add path into C's code, but is there another way to access these modules? For instance using `__init__.py` file.

**Note**

I have had problems when using `from . import ...` and `from .. import ...`

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.Package'; '__main__' is not a package
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Thanks for your reply

Comment: `import Package.A  as A ` and `import Package.subpackage.B as B`

Comment: Add lines in C.py file

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. 
```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Package'
```

Comment: Tell me the output of `print(sys.path)`

Comment: Neither  `C:\...\Packages\subpackage` or `C:\...\Packages\subpackage\subsuspackage` is included

Comment: Do, `sys.path.insert(0,"Path/to/Package directory")` and execute your script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python import module from parent package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250058/python-import-module-from-parent-package)

Comment: @Grismar Iit could be the anwer but i don't know how to make helper script, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Always a party, trying to get this to work. Would this meet your needs?

A structure like this:

```
> package_a
  > package_b
    > package_c
      c.py
      __init__.py
    b.py
    __init__.py
  a.py
  __init__.py
```

The `package_a\a.py` would have something like:

```
def some_a():
    print('a here')
```

And `package_a\__init__`:

```
from .a import some_a
```

Similar for `b`. `c.py` would then work like this (assuming you're running `some_c.py` directly, or calling):

```
from package_a import some_a
from package_a.package_b import some_b


def some_c():
    print('c here')
    some_b()
    some_a()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    some_c()
```

I.e. not using relative imports from the outside packages, but actually referring to the package names that sit outside it.

If this is not what you need, you need to provide more specifics about what those packages look like on the inside and why this would not work.