# Python import error- No Module named error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to import one python file in another. I have the following directory structure -

```
/a/program.py
/b/python_package/test.py
/b/python_package/__init__.py
```

Program. py-

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/b/python_package')
import test
```

also tried

```
from python_package import test
```

Test.py-

```
print('imported package')
```

I am getting no module named test error.

```
ImportError: No module named test in <script> at line number 5
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<script>", line 7, in <module>
ImportError: No module named test
None
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the full error message

Comment: (1) You mixed "python_package" and "python_packages". (2) For the second variant the appended path should only be "/b" anyway.

Comment: @wjandrea this is the full message

Comment: @MichaelButscher corrected but still getiing the error

Comment: @user2828360 What is the full message?

Comment: @wjandrea 
ImportError: No module named test in <script> at line number 5

Comment: @user2828360 Please include the traceback too

Comment: @wjandrea Added.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__.py` signs a dir as a python package in python 2, in python 3 it is not needed.

You should check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250058/python-import-module-from-parent-package).

Are a, b totally different paths?
You can have something like this:

```
root/
  program.py
  package/
    b.py
```

Then you can import the b module in program like:

```
from package import b
```

Comment: The way the directory is structured it should be different paths only

Answer (score 0):

You have to do an absolute import and sys.insert method works

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/abs_path/b/python_package')
import test
```

It is actually a dirty trick, the right way to do is to create a package and import from parent its child. Note it is not init.py it is `___init___.py`

Comment: 1. I have added the absolute path only. Its only specifies like /b to simplify. Also getting the same error with insert? Also its " __init__.py" only

Comment: yes, I can see the init has be edited now, is your folder b in root? i.e /b