# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app' How to fix it?

Tags: python, flask, directory

The structure of my project is:

[directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78cbW.png)

From test.py I am trying to import models using *from app.models import User*, but I am getting an error indicating the app module wasn't found.
Also, tried *from .models import User*

Anyone can help me understand what I am missing?

Comment: You can try this answer. Hope it helps you [https://stackoverflow.com/a/40046317/5643944](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40046317/5643944)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely in the incorrect working directory. You can check your current directory using.

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

I assume you are in the 'tests' directory, and therefore need to go back one. If so, you can try:

```
import os
os.chdir('..')
from app.models import User
```

Comment: I am in the project directory. user\ desktop\ project

Comment: Did this really solve the issue? Not working for me...

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```
from ..models import User
```

Comment: No luck. ImportError: Attempted relative import with no known parent package

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to set `FLASK_APP` variable and try.

```
export FLASK_APP=<path_to-run.py>
```

For power shell:

```
set FLASK_APP=<path_to-run.py>
$env:FLASK_APP = "<path_to-run.py>"
```